# How to force update when using superagent cache?

Tags: caching, superagent

I am using superagent-cache and superagent.

For most of my requests, I use this:

```
import superagentCache from 'superagent';
const superagent = superagentCache();
```

superagent is using the cache as expected.

For some request, I want to use the superagent and not the cache.

```
import superagent from "superagent";
```

But for even those requests, superagent continues to use the cached response. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

superagent-cache patches the existing superagent. So, it is not possible to have the original superagent.

To avoid caching or force AJAX requests, use the forceUpdate param on the superagent-cache.

Comment: You can also use `superagent-cache-plugin` if you prefer to not patch superagent globally. This will allow you to apply the cache and its options on a per-request basis.